# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 51 -

Tags: php

new here and have an issue. I'm trying to find a parse error in the code. It says "line 51" in the message, but I've tried deleting, tags and no resolve. Can someone point me in the right direction as I'm really new to php

```
<?php
/**
 * Variable product add to cart
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.4.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
 }

 global $product;

 $attribute_keys = array_keys( $attributes );

 do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" method="post"      enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint(   $product->id ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !==   $available_variations ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is  currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
  <?php else : ?>
    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo    sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                            $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                            wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected, 'class' => 'sc-combobox' ) );
                            echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' : '';
                        ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

    <div class="single_variation_wrap" style="display:none;">
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_single_variation Hook
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );

          <div class="single_variation clearfix"></div>     <<--THIS IS LINE 51

        <div class="variations_button">
            <?php woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : 1 ) ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="sc-button single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="" />
        </div>

            /**
             * woocommerce_after_single_variation Hook
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'scalia' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
</form>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

Comment: you never closed your PHP tag `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );` so.... `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );?>` - question's off-topic btw. oh and didn't reopen the other block.

Comment: The way you would debug something like is to start commenting out lines. Keep commenting out code until the page loads properly. The last comment   you put in before proper execution is where the problem is.

Comment: Never believe everything that PHP says, it's usually the line above X-number.

Comment: *in, out... in, out...* - just like a roll in the hay. Remember that.

Answer (score 0):

In this block you're opening a PHP block twice without closing a previous one.

```
<?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_single_variation Hook
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );

          <div class="single_variation clearfix"></div>     <<--THIS IS LINE 51

        <div class="variations_button">
            <?php woocommerce_quantity_input
```

Comment: you missed something here.

Comment: what are they going to do about `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );`? and the div after it?

Comment: Thank you Alfabravo, that's an answer I can work with, just have to figure it out now...when I said I'm new to .php, I mean, I just opened a book today, literally.

Comment: Fred -ii-, can you elaborate

Comment: Okay, fixed that issue, now I just have random code under my add to cart button  `code` - /** * woocommerce_after_single_variation Hook */ do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' ); ?>

This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.`code`